# How to set up an event listener using the latest version of @react-native-community/netinfo?

Tags: react-native, redux-saga, react-native-community-netinfo

I've been trying to set up an event listener to get connection changes using the latest version of @react-native-community/netinfo and redux-saga, but I could not make it work. Could you help me?

This code used to work in previously versions:

```js
import { put, take } from "redux-saga/effects";
import { eventChannel } from "redux-saga";
import { NetInfo } from "react-native";
import { OFFLINE, ONLINE } from "redux-offline-queue";

export function* startWatchingNetworkConnectivity() {
  const channel = eventChannel(emitter => {
    NetInfo.isConnected.addEventListener("connectionChange", emitter);
    return () =>
      NetInfo.isConnected.removeEventListener("connectionChange", emitter);
  });

  try {
      const isConnected = yield take(channel);

      if (isConnected) {
        yield put({ type: ONLINE });
      } else {
        yield put({ type: OFFLINE });
      }
  } finally {
    channel.close();
  }
}
```

Now I have this one:

```js
import { take, put } from 'redux-saga/effects';
import { eventChannel } from 'redux-saga';
import NetInfo from '@react-native-community/netinfo';
import { OFFLINE, ONLINE } from 'redux-offline-queue';

export function* startWatchingNetworkConnectivity() {
  const channel = eventChannel(emitter =>
    NetInfo.addEventListener(state => state.isConnected)
  );

  try {
    while (true) {
      const isConnected = yield take(channel);

      if (isConnected) {
        yield put({ type: ONLINE })
      } else {
        yield put({ type: OFFLINE })
      }
    }
  } finally {
    channel.close();
  }
}
```

Regards,

Erick

Comment: Have you tried importing NetInfo as -> import * as NetInfo from '@react-native-community/netinfo';

Comment: @likeachamp I tried to import that way but it didn't work.